# SSH Tunnel - channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

Tags: ssh, centos7, tcp, ssh-tunnel, socks

```
ssh -D 9090 user@host
```

when I try to request web pages through socks5 (127.0.0.1:9090) I get:

```
channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

server sshd_config:

```
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
PermitTunnel yes
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding yes
        PermitTTY yes
#       ForceCommand cvs server
#       PermitTunnel yes
        GatewayPorts       yes
```

what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old question ... but in case someone lands here via Google.

Check out  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open
It has a number of suggested fixes.

By the way, why did you post a question when this question has been asked many times?

Comment: I actually don't remember :), I guess I wanted to share the config file, because it looked okay to me but didn't work.